# Morph 2 elements with anchor animation

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

There are 2 elements on the same view.
One is removed from DOM at the same time when other is inserted.

I want to use anchor animation to morph between those 2 elements.

**HTML**

```
<button ng-click="showDiv = !showDiv">Anchor Animation</button>

<div ng-if="!showDiv" ng-animate-ref="anchor1" class="anchor1-animation" style="position:absolute; left:150px; top:90px; background:#FE367F; width:50px; height:50px"></div>

<div ng-if="showDiv" ng-animate-ref="anchor1" class="anchor1-animation" style="position:absolute; right:50px; top:250px; background:#3396F1; width:200px; height:200px"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.anchor1-animation.ng-enter, .anchor1-animation.ng-leave {
  @include transition(all 50ms linear);
}

.anchor1-animation.ng-anchor-out {
  @include transition(all 0ms linear);
}

.anchor1-animation.ng-anchor-in {
  @include transition(all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.230, 1.000, 0.320, 1.000));
}
```

This works on all browsers except on Safari, its driving me crazy!

It works on Chrome, Firefox, IE10+, Edge.

Comment: Can you replicate it in a Plunker?